# При попытке создания пустого окна в Kivy появляется ошибка

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

При вызове функции MyApp().run() появляется ошибка.

```
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()





[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\MrKan\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-04-22_39.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\MrKan\Projects\venv\New2\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\MrKan\Projects\venv\New2\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
  File "D:\MrKan\Projects\venv\New2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "D:\MrKan\Projects\venv\New2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Answer (score 0):

Пустое окно можно так создать:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Box()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```